# Transform array of objects with reduce and javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I´d like to transsform it in a other.

I can do it with a for loop, but I´d like to use reduce.
How could I do it using reduce?

```
const arr=[
  { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv1", subtotal: 10 },
  { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 10 },
  { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 20 },
  { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 20 },
  { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 25 },
  { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat3", convenio: "conv4", subtotal: 15 },
  { medico: 'med2', rateio: 'rat4', convenio: 'conv3', subtotal: 10 },
];
```

I need the next result:

```
const result=[
  {medico: "med1", grantotals:[
    {
      rateio: "rat1",
      grandtotals: [
        { convenio: "conv1", sum_subtotal: 10 },
        { convenio: "conv3", sum_subtotal: 45 }
      ]
    }
  ]},
  {medico: "med2", grantotals:[
      {
        rateio: "rat2",
        grandtotals: [
          { convenio: "conv2", sum_subtotal: 30 },
        ]
      },
      {
        rateio: "rat3",
        grandtotals: [
          { convenio: "conv4", sum_subtotal: 15 },
        ]
      },
      {
        rateio: "rat4",
        grandtotals: [
          { convenio: "conv3", sum_subtotal: 10 },
        ]
      }
    ]}
    ]
```

Comment: If you already have a `for`-loop-based solution, why would you exchange it for a `.reduce()`-based?

Comment: Hi, First to learn and second because it's more elegant with less code

Comment: Share your for loop solutions. It won't be hard to convert to reduce once you are done with basic for loop.

Comment: Ok I will do and I will post it asap

Comment: Basically, `res = arr.reduce(fn)` is, more or less, the same as `res = ...; for (i in arr) { res = fn(res, arr[i]); }`. Since you have the `for` variant, it is easy to extract the code into the `fn()` function.

Comment: This structure is invalid: `medico: "med1", [`. Please post proper expected output.

Comment: @Unmitigated I just fixed it

Comment: Don't abuse reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `reduce()` method in JavaScript, Here below I demonstrate how to apply `reduce()` to convert the arr array into the desired result array structure:

1. The `reduce()` method is used to iterate over the `arr` array and transform the data into the desired structure.
2. For each object (`obj`) in the `arr` array. We check if there is an existing `medico` object in the `acc` array using the `find()` method.
3. If an existing `medico` object is found, we continue searching for the existing `rateio` object within that `medico` object.
4. If an existing `rateio` object is found, we continue searching for the existing `convenio` object within that `rateio` object.
5. If an existing `convenio` object is found, we update the `sum_subtotal` property by adding the subtotal value to it.
6. If an existing `convenio` object is not found, we create a new `convenio` object and push it into the grandtotals array within the existing rateio object.
7. If an existing `rateio` object is not found, we create a new `rateio` object with the corresponding convenio object and push it into the grantotals array within the existing medico object.
8. If an existing medico object is not found, we create a new `medico` object with the corresponding `rateio` and `convenio` objects and push it into the `acc` array.
9. Finally, the transformed `acc` array is returned as the result array. Is there anything else I can help you with?

```js
const arr = [
    { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv1", subtotal: 10 },
    { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 10 },
    { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 20 },
    { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 20 },
    { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 25 },
    { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat3", convenio: "conv4", subtotal: 15 },
    { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat4", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 10 },
  ];
  
  const result = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const existingMedico = acc.find((item) => item.medico === obj.medico);
  
    if (existingMedico) {
      const existingRateio = existingMedico.grantotals.find(
        (item) => item.rateio === obj.rateio
      );
  
      if (existingRateio) {
        const existingConvenio = existingRateio.grandtotals.find(
          (item) => item.convenio === obj.convenio
        );
  
        if (existingConvenio) {
          existingConvenio.sum_subtotal += obj.subtotal;
        } else {
          existingRateio.grandtotals.push({
            convenio: obj.convenio,
            sum_subtotal: obj.subtotal,
          });
        }
      } else {
        existingMedico.grantotals.push({
          rateio: obj.rateio,
          grandtotals: [
            {
              convenio: obj.convenio,
              sum_subtotal: obj.subtotal,
            },
          ],
        });
      }
    } else {
      acc.push({
        medico: obj.medico,
        grantotals: [
          {
            rateio: obj.rateio,
            grandtotals: [
              {
                convenio: obj.convenio,
                sum_subtotal: obj.subtotal,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      });
    }
  
    return acc;
  }, []);
  
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is ChatGPT working again?

Comment: Hi, It´s great and so fast. Thank you. Are you using chatgpt? (kiding...)

Comment: No first solve it on replit. Then write explain of it. here it's link
https://replit.com/@AbdulMoeez3/stackoverflow-reduce-and-javascript?v=1

Comment: alternative you can also solve it with the combination of reducer and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to fold your input into a format like this, using `reduce`:

```js
{
    med1: {
        rat1: {conv1: 10, conv3: 45}
    },
    med2: {
        rat2: {conv2: 30},
        rat3: {conv4: 15},
        rat4: {conv3: 10}
    }
}
```

and rehydrating with your property names, by repeatedly using `Object.entries` and mapping the results.  It turns out relatively straightforward:

```js
const restructure = (xs) => {
  const compressed = xs.reduce((a, {medico, rateio, convenio, subtotal}) => {
    a[medico] ||= {}
    a[medico][rateio] ||= {}
    a[medico][rateio][convenio] ||= 0
      a[medico][rateio][convenio] += subtotal
    return a
  }, {})
  return Object.entries(compressed).map(([medico, grantotals]) => ({
    medico, 
    grantotals: Object.entries(grantotals).map(([rateio, grandtotals]) => ({
      rateio, 
      grandtotals: Object.entries(grandtotals).map(([convenio, sum_subtotal]) => ({
        convenio, 
        sum_subtotal
      })) 
  }))
}))}

const arr = [{medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv1", subtotal: 10}, {medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 10}, {medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 20}, {medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 20}, {medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 25}, {medico: "med2", rateio: "rat3", convenio: "conv4", subtotal: 15}, {medico: 'med2', rateio: 'rat4', convenio: 'conv3', subtotal: 10}]

console.log(restructure(arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`compressed` is the format above, which we create by what is essentially a nested `groupBy` function.  Then we return an object which works its way inward along the nested properties, using `Object.entries` to create the key-value pairs, and mapping those to simple objects.

Answer (score 0):

Added an explanation in the comments:

```js
const arr = [
  { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv1", subtotal: 10 },
  { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 10 },
  { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat2", convenio: "conv2", subtotal: 20 },
  { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 20 },
  { medico: "med1", rateio: "rat1", convenio: "conv3", subtotal: 25 },
  { medico: "med2", rateio: "rat3", convenio: "conv4", subtotal: 15 },
  { medico: 'med2', rateio: 'rat4', convenio: 'conv3', subtotal: 10 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((prev, current) => {
  const { medico, rateio, convenio, subtotal } = current;
  /* Searching medico */
  const medicoIndex = prev.findIndex(o => o.medico === medico);
  /* If medico doesn't exists */
  if (medicoIndex < 0) {
    prev.push({
      medico: medico,
      grandtotals: [{
        rateio: rateio,
        grandtotals: [
          {
            convenio: convenio,
            subtotal: subtotal
          }
        ]
      }]
    })
  } else {
    const medicoValut = prev[medicoIndex];
    /* Searching rateio */
    const rateioIndex = medicoValut.grandtotals.findIndex(o => o.rateio === rateio);
    /* If rateio doesn't exists */
    if (rateioIndex < 0) {
      medicoValut.grandtotals.push({
        rateio: rateio,
        grandtotals: [{
          convenio: convenio,
          subtotal: subtotal,
        }]
      })
    } else {
      const convenioValue = medicoValut.grandtotals[rateioIndex];
      /* Searching convenio */
      const convenioIndex = convenioValue.grandtotals.findIndex(o => o.convenio === convenio);
      /* If convenio doesn't exists */
      if (convenioIndex < 0){
        convenioValue.grandtotals.push({
          convenio: convenio,
          subtotal: subtotal,
        })
      }else{
        /* Else add subtotal */
        convenioValue.grandtotals[convenioIndex].subtotal += subtotal;
      }
    }
  }
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```